# Does MS Word have an equivalent to ExecuteExcel4Macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Chip Pearson *RIP* documented a feature in Excel `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(HiddenName)`.

This feature provides a nicely hidden application level space for addins to store information... have a look: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/hidden.htm

Is there something similar available for MS Word?

I tried intellisense but there is nothing that starts with `Application.Ex`

Comment: no. you can use custom xml parts. read this :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/customxmlparts-object-office here is a full read/write example http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2018/01/embedding-and-retrieving-information-in.html

Comment: @cyboashu thanks for the suggestion. To be honest I'd not be surprised if the answer is NO. That said I already use custom xml parts but they are part of a specified document, becoming unavailable when that document is closed.

Comment: Other than what @cyboashu said, you'd need to write to a file, or to the Registry. Word does have System.PrivateProfileString (I think that's the name - I'm typing from memory on a mobile device) which Excel does not have :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you for clarifying. I also use system profile string. Actually I use it to store a pointer to the Ribbon (for those times when things `End` unexpectedly); I was hoping something like _ExecuteWord4Macro_ could replace that workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It would seem that the answer is No

Thank you cyboashu and Cindy Meister for your comments. The nice thing about ExecuteExcel4Macro is that it allows developers to place content in a very private space; apparently it is not possible (or extremely difficult) to read from this hidden space unless you know exactly what you're looking for, and it persists until all documents are closed.

There are various workarounds for MS Word:

- ini file (system.PrivateProfileString) *(not private, file persists when application closes)*
- customXML parts *(tied to an instance of a document, dies with document)*
- document variables *(tied to an instance of a document, dies with document)*

Good as they are, these approaches are not quite what I was after (my question was more out of interest than actual need).

---

I had also thought of:

Creating an Excel object in Word and using the feature that way, but I think the same issue remains if things `End` suddenly. Similarly, I think a purpose built DLL would also fall victim to `End`.